# Difficulty in NULL concept in C?

Tags: c

NULL in C programming can anyone tell me how NULL is handled in C?
And the output of this program is 3, how with NULL concept?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    static int count;
    for(i = NULL; i <= 5;) {
        count++;
        i += 2;
    }

    printf("%d\n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is just a macro defined in `stdio.h` or a file that stdio includes. It can variously be defined as some variation of zero.

If you run your code through the C pre-processor (usually `cc -E`) you can see what it translates to on your implemnentation:

```
void main(){
    int i;
    static int count;
    for(i=((void *)0); i<=5 ;){
       count++;
       i+=2;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
}
```

which is not only an unnecessary use of `NULL` but is wildly un-idiomatic C code, more ordinary would be:

```
int main(){
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= 5; i += 2){
       count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @me_eclair: it's `3` because you are counting to `5` by `2`'s look at the last part of the `for` loop. It is adding `2` each iteration, so `i` goes like this: `0` -> `2` -> `4` -> `6`. The loop is not entered when `i == 6` so the body of the loop is only run 3 times.

Comment: NULL is defined in <stddef.h>. You don't need to include <stdio.h>. In particular, you can use NULL in a freestanding environment without including <stdio.h> (which ought to be unavailable).

Answer (score 21):

For C, "NULL" is traditionally defined to be (void *)0 - in other words, it's a pointer alias to address 0.  For C++, "NULL" is typically defined to be "0".  The problem with NULL in C++ and C is that it's not type safe - you can build bizarre constructs like the one you included in your code sample.

For C++, the language designers fixed this in C++0x by adding a new "nullptr" type which is implicitly convertable to any pointer type but which cannot be converted to an integer type.

Comment: NULL is not an alias to address 0 (which could be a valid address).  It's an integer *constant* zero in a pointer context.

Comment: There is no concept of "pointer zero" because pointer addition does not have an identity element. `NULL` is a macro which expands to a canonical invalid pointer, which happens not to be strongly typed.

Answer (score 3):

There's a whole chapter devoted to the Null pointer in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html) that should answer all your questions.

- 5.1 What is this infamous null pointer, anyway?
- 5.2 How do I get a null pointer in my programs?
- 5.3 Is the abbreviated pointer comparison `if(p)` to test for non-null pointers valid? What if the internal representation for null pointers is nonzero?
- 5.4 What is `NULL` and how is it defined?
- 5.5 How should NULL be defined on a machine which uses a nonzero bit pattern as the internal representation of a null pointer?
- 5.6 If `NULL` were defined as follows: `#define NULL ((char *)0)`. Wouldn't that make function calls which pass an uncast NULL work?
- 5.7 My vendor provides header files that #define NULL as 0L. Why?
- 5.8 Is `NULL` valid for pointers to functions?
- 5.9 If `NULL` and 0 are equivalent as null pointer constants, which should I use?
- 5.10 But wouldn't it be better to use `NULL` (rather than 0), in case the value of `NULL` changes, perhaps on a machine with nonzero internal null pointers?
- 5.11 I once used a compiler that wouldn't work unless `NULL` was used.
- 5.12 I use the preprocessor macro `#define Nullptr(type) (type *)0` to help me build null pointers of the correct type.
- 5.13 This is strange. `NULL` is guaranteed to be 0, but the null pointer is not?
- 5.14 Why is there so much confusion surrounding null pointers? Why do these questions come up so often?
- 5.15 I'm confused. I just can't understand all this null pointer stuff.
- 5.16 Given all the confusion surrounding null pointers, wouldn't it be easier simply to require them to be represented internally by zeroes?
- 5.17 Seriously, have any actual machines really used nonzero null pointers, or different representations for pointers to different types?
- 5.18 Is a run-time integral value of 0, cast to a pointer, guaranteed to be a null pointer?
- 5.19 How can I access an interrupt vector located at the machine's location 0? If I set a pointer to 0, the compiler might translate it to some nonzero internal null pointer value.
- 5.20 What does a run-time ``null pointer assignment'' error mean? How can I track it down?

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` has most of its meaning when dealing with pointers. When dealing with integers, you would be better off using simply zero.

Strictly speaking, `NULL` is simply the value zero with a fancy name, but the most important part about it is indeed its fancy name. It exists because it's less ambiguous to write `int* p = NULL;` than `int* p = 0;`. Since we know `NULL` is a pointer, we're sure that I really meant `p` to be a pointer.

So, when you deal with pointers and want to represent the *address* `0`, use `NULL`. And when you deal with numbers and want to represent the *number* `0`, use `0`. (In your example, you should use `0` instead of `NULL`.)

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is should be synonymous with `0`. It's more correctly used to indicate a null pointer.

In this case the code will actually be:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5)
{
    count++;
    i += 2;
}
```

Comment: correction, it depends on the standard library, not the compiler. The language specs for both C and C++ are very clear about what `NULL` may be.

Comment: @Evan - thanks, it's a while since I did C in anger. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is defined as 0 by C. In your program, it counts from 0 to 5 (counting every 2nd number). That's why count is 3 (i = 0, 2, 4).

NULL shouldn't be used this way. NULL should be used with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `NULL` and the type of `i` are different, but `C` forgives you :)

`C` is (mostly) not a "type-safe" language. I mean: it lets you mix types which other languages would complain.

With `C` you can add `chars` to `doubles`, you can multiply `chars` and `ints`, ...

What you are doing is assigning a `null pointer constant` (of type `void *`) to an `int`. `C` allows that, but **you need to be very careful when mixing types** like this.

The result of assigning the null pointer constant to an int is the same as assigning `0` to it. So you start your loop with `i` being `0`.

A static auto variable, in the absence of an initializer, is initialized to `0`. This happens to the variable `count` in your program.

So, the loop goes first (`count` becomes 1) with `i` being 0, then `i` becomes 2.
Now the loop goes (`count` becomes 2) with `i` being 2, then `i` becomes 4.
Now the loop goes (`count` becomes 3) with `i` being 4, then `i` becomes 6.
And the loop terminates ... and you print the value of `count`.

---

**Notes**

- to be Standard compliant `main` should be declared `int main(void)`
- you should output a newline after every complete line ( `printf("%d\n", count);` )
- and you should `return 0;` to indicate successful completion of your program to the Operating System

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the idea of a NULL pointer in c with that of a nullable type or quantities in some dynamic languages. There are similar, but have distinct uses and meaning.

In c the concept of NULL is only used natively in the context of pointer where it is a pointer to a *known invalid* memory location (often, but not always, represented by zero).

This is not (quite) the same as a type or variable which can represent non-setness. Note that types like this can be defined-and-managed by the user in c, but they are not supplied by the language.